# Перенести код С++ с std::map на СИ

Tags: c++, c, vector, map

Есть код на С++ в нём используются `std::vector` и `std::map`.
Мне нужно перенести код на язык СИ где нет STL, делать реализацию методов из STL `vector` и `map` для массива в языке СИ не требуется. Нужно лишь перенести данную конструкцию на средства языка СИ. 
Как это записано в С++
Пример: `std::vector <тип> myVector;`
Как я это записал c использованием языка СИ:

```
<тип> * myVector;  
int sizeMyVector;
```

Как мне правильно перенести конструкцию из языка С++ с использованием `map` на язык Си с использованием простых массивов? Конструкции такие:
1) `map <int , double> myFirstMap;`
2) `map<int, map<int, double> >;`

Comment: Реализация не требуется? Тогда непонятно, в чём смысл. Скажем, как вы переведёте на Си `myVector.push_back(что_нибудь)`?

Comment: Как-то странно звучит - делать реализацию методов не надо. Но тогда теряется весь смысл map! все его свойства...

Comment: вам вероятно что-то вроде [`libavl` библиотеки (первое попавшееся)](http://adtinfo.org/) нужно, чтобы эмулировать в С `map<>` или если вам нужно `unordered_map<>`, то можно [одно из многочисленных hash table реализаций взять](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1138742/4279)

Comment: Нет, вам нужна именно функциональность `map`. Так что вам придётся переписывать этот класс на C. Да, это много работы, чреватой ошибками. Массивы не моделируют `map`.

Comment: http://attractivechaos.awardspace.com/

Comment: [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/)

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то это комментарий, но там не поместится...

Ну вот объявите вы, например, так:

```
typedef struct pair_
{
    int a;
    double b;
} pair;
typedef struct map_
{
    int x;
    pair * p;
} map;

pair* myFirstMap;
map*  mySecondMap;
```

Но что толку без реализации? Ведь нужно обеспечить отсортированность, единственность, время доступа... Т.е. по сути реализовать сбалансированное бинарное дерево. И опять же - нужны именно функции для работы с ним, потому что иначе - это просто какой-то сюр...

Comment: std::map это зависящая от платформы технология. Мне нужно привести std::map и std::vector к POD типу. Для того чтобы свободно экспортировать функции между языками СИ и С++. А экспортировать функции, производимые от шаблонов stl очень трудно.

Comment: D лучшем случае у вас получится что-то типа велосипеда, перевязанного веревочками, но с рулем и эмблемой от "Мерса". От эого ни комфорта, ни тем более скорости не будет. Пойтите - `map` не тип, это целая концепция! Что и куда вы хотите экспортировать? Может, вы изложите **исходную задачу**, потому что ваш вопрос очень напоминает "*за какое место следует держать микроскоп при забивании трехдююймовых гвоздей?*"...

Comment: Это делается для бинарной совместимости между компиляторами. У меня задача выдать структуры и объявление функции с аргументами которая она использует(.h файл) и определение функции внутри которой стоит заглушка(.cpp файл). Я не знаю каким компилятором будет собирать мой .h (со структурами и объявлением функции) и файл (.cpp). Возможно тем же как использую я, но разной версии, а может и вовсе другим. Я не знаю каким он будет пользоваться компилятором С или С++. И если он будет использовать компилятор СИ то если внутри структуры есть std::vector и std::map у него просто не соберутся исходники.

Comment: @Harry ну чисто в теории можно же сделать плоский map используя свой аллокатор в нём? А потом это загнать как POD в обычный поток байт... Или это совсем изврат?

Comment: @Disastricks я тогда вам бы посоветовал http://e-maxx.ru/algo/treap изучить. Оно вполне в массив загоняется обычный.

Comment: Другой человек будет уже делать реализацию с тем что я ему выдал и собирать библиотеку и отдаваь её мне. И возможно он использует компилятор СИ а не С++ и другой версии. Поэтому было принято решение передавать в функцию только POD типы и в структуры использовать тоже их, а не std::map и std::vector.

Comment: И вот пример как я например заменил вектор std::vector <тип> myVector; На вариант для СИ <тип> * myVector;  
int sizeMyVector;  Где в функцию будет передаваться адрес массива и его размер

Comment: Ну, тогда можно использовать те структуры, что я привел в ответе - разве что с pair p[] в конце, а не с указателем... Может, еще и с полем количества записей.